# How does stat command calculate the blocks of a file?

Tags: linux, filesystems

I am wondering how the `stat` command calculates the number of blocks for a file. I read this [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20090214110539/http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl2_stat.htm) that says:

> The value st_blocks gives the size of the file in 512-byte blocks. (This may be smaller than st_size/512 e.g. when the file has holes.) The value st_blksize gives the "preferred" blocksize for efficient file system I/O. (Writing to a file in smaller chunks may cause an inefficient read-modify-rewrite.)

Yet I cannot verify this with my own tests.

My file system is ext3.

The command `dumpe2fs -h /dev/sda3` shows:

```
...
First block: 0
Block size: 4096
Fragment size: 4096
...
```

Then I run

```
kent@KentT60:~/Desktop$ stat Email
File: `Email'
Size: 965 Blocks: 8 IO Block: 4096 regular file
Device: 80ah/2058d Inode: 746095 Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--) Uid: ( 1000/ kent) Gid: ( 1000/ kent)
Access: 2009-08-11 21:36:36.000000000 +0200
Modify: 2009-08-11 21:36:35.000000000 +0200
Change: 2009-08-11 21:36:35.000000000 +0200
```

If "Blocks" here means: "how many 512 bytes blocks", the number should be 2, not 8. I thought that the block size of the file system (IO block) is 4k.

If the file system gets the file `Email`, it will fetch a minimum of 4k from the disk (8 x 512 bytes blocks), which means 965/512 + 6 = 8. I am not sure if this guess is correct.

Another test:

```
kent@KentT60:~/Desktop$ stat wxPython-demo-2.8.10.1.tar.bz2
File: `wxPython-demo-2.8.10.1.tar.bz2'
Size: 3605257 Blocks: 7056 IO Block: 4096 regular file
Device: 80ah/2058d Inode: 746210 Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--) Uid: ( 1000/ kent) Gid: ( 1000/ kent)
Access: 2009-08-12 21:45:45.000000000 +0200
Modify: 2009-08-12 21:43:46.000000000 +0200
Change: 2009-08-12 21:43:46.000000000 +0200


3605257/512=7041.xx = 7042
```

Following my guess above, this would be 7042 + 6 = 7048. But the `stat` result shows 7056.

And another example from the internet at `https://www.computerhope.com/unix/stat.htm`. I pasted the example at the bottom of the page here:

```
File: `index.htm'
Size: 17137 Blocks: 40 IO Block: 8192 regular file
Device: 8h/8d Inode: 23161443 Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--) Uid: (17433/comphope) Gid: ( 32/ www)
Access: 2007-04-03 09:20:18.000000000 -0600
Modify: 2007-04-01 23:13:05.000000000 -0600
Change: 2007-04-02 16:36:21.000000000 -0600
```

In this example, the file system block size is 8k. I suppose the "Blocks" value should be 16xN, but it is 40. I'm getting lost...

Can anyone explain how `stat` calculates the "Blocks" value?

Thanks!

Comment: `stat`'s output is a bit treacherous: The block size of "Blocks" is 512 bytes whereas the block size of "IO Block" is commonly 4096 bytes (for ext4). I tried to get at bottom of this in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/946521/what-is-the-meaning-io-block-and-how-to-calculate/1308745#1308745).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `stat` command-line tool uses the `stat` / `fstat` etc. functions, which return data in the `stat` structure. The `st_blocks` member of the `stat` structure returns:

> The total number of physical blocks of size 512 bytes actually allocated on disk. This field is not defined for block special or character special files.

So for your "Email" example, with a size of 965 and a block count of 8, it is indicating that 8*512=4096 bytes are physically allocated on disk. The reason it's not 2 is that the file system on disk does not allocate space in units of 512, it evidently allocates them in units of 4096. (And the unit of allocation may vary depending on file size and filesystem sophistication. E.g. ZFS supports different units of allocation.)

Similarly, for the wxPython example, it indicates that 7056*512 bytes, or 3612672 bytes are physically allocated on disk. You get the idea.

The IO block size is "a hint as to the 'best' unit size for I/O operations" - it's usually the unit of allocation on the physical disk. Don't get confused between the IO block and the block that `stat` uses to indicate physical size; the blocks for physical size are always 512 bytes.

Update based on comment:

Like I said, `st_blocks` is how the OS indicates how much space is used by the file on disk. The actual units of allocation on disk are the choice of the file system. For example, ZFS can have allocation blocks of variable size, *even in the same file*, because of the way it allocates blocks: files start out having a small block size, and the block size keeps on increasing until it reaches a particular point. If the file is later truncated, it will probably keep the old block size. So based on the history of the file, it can have multiple possible block sizes. So given a file size it is not always obvious why it has a particular physical size.

Concrete example: on my Solaris box, with a ZFS file system, I can create a very short file:

```
$ echo foo > test
$ stat test
  Size: 4               Blocks: 2          IO Block: 512    regular file
(irrelevant details omitted)
```

OK, small file, 2 blocks, physical disk usage is 1024 for this file.

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=test2 bs=8192 count=4
$ stat test2
  Size: 32768           Blocks: 65         IO Block: 32768  regular file
```

OK, now we see physical disk usage of 32.5K, and an IO block size of 32K. I then copied it to `test3` and truncated this `test3` file in an editor:

```
$ cp test2 test3
$ joe -hex test3
$ stat test3
  Size: 4               Blocks: 65         IO Block: 32768  regular file
```

Well now, here's a file with 4 bytes in it - just like `test` - but it's using 32.5K physically on the disk, because of the way the ZFS file system allocates space. Block sizes increase as the file gets larger, but they don't decrease when the file gets smaller. (And yes, this can lead to substantial wasted space depending on the kinds of files and file operations you do on ZFS, which is why it allows you to set the maximum block size on a per-filesystem basis, and change it dynamically.)

Hopefully, you can now appreciate that there isn't necessarily a simple relationship between file size and physical disk usage. Even in the above it's not clear why 32.5K bytes are needed to store a file that's exactly 32K in size - it appears that ZFS generally needs an extra 512 bytes for extra storage of its own. Perhaps it's using that storage for checksums, reference counts, transaction state - file system bookkeeping. By including these extras in the indicated physical file size, it seems like ZFS is trying not to mislead the user as to the physical costs of the file. That doesn't mean it's trivial to reverse-engineer the calculation without knowing intimate details about the underlying file system implementation.

Comment: Agreed.  `st_blocks` is only called that for historical reasons.  Don't think of it as blocks, but as the amount of disk space used by the file, in units of 512 bytes.  512 bytes is a convenient unit because it is pretty much the smallest allocation unit that anyone uses.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination. almost clear. 
but still have questions.  i am not sure if it is correct understanding:

st_blocks = (IO block size / 512) *  (how many IO blocks the file used).  
Email example can be explained by this: (4096/512) * 1 = 8
wxpython one not. because the file used 881 IO blocks, and (4096/512)*881=7048 not 7056.

and the last example not either:
40 can even not be exactly divided by  16 (8192/512)..

is the "512bytes" for all system the same?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

im not talking about complex FS like ZFS 
but as for simple fs like ext2: 
-stat output field "IO Block" shows "ext2 filesystem block size" 
-stat output field "Blocks"  shows  number of non-existent virtual  blocks (512-byte each). that is stat gives files size from "Size" filed , divide to 512 and put it in the answer. \

an example.
a file has the size of 2 bytes.

```
# od -t x1 ./1
0000000 31 0a
0000002
```

a file system is formatted with fs block size 4K
lets look at stat

```
# stat 1
  File: 1
  Size: 2           Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 811h/2065d  Inode: 12          Links: 1
```

IO Block shows 4096, that is 4K , that is ext2 fs block size.  as file can not occupy the space less then fs block size then 2 bytes reside in a fs block 4K = 4096 bytes.
we divide 4096 by 512 and get 8. This is the number in "Blocks" field.

lets take another ext2 fs with 1K fs block size.

```
# stat 1
  File: 1
  Size: 2           Blocks: 2          IO Block: 1024   regular file
```

IO Block = 1024 ,  this is exatctly what fs block size is.(1K)

the file can not occupy amount of disk less then 1K. so 2bytes occupy 1K disk size.

we divide 1024 by 512 and get 2.
this is exactly what we see in

```
Blocks: 2
```